# Can I decode a C++ exception from a Windows SEH exception? (And if so, how?)

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, exception

In the event of an unhandled C++ exception I want to print:

1. The message (`what()`) of the C++ exception
2. A stack trace.

In order to get the stack trace, I'm using `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` in combination with the [StackWalker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack) library:

```
struct FooStackWalker : StackWalker
{
    virtual void OnCallstackEntry(CallstackEntryType, CallstackEntry &entry) override
    {
        std::cerr << entry.lineFileName << " (" << entry.lineNumber << "): " << entry.undFullName << std::endl;
    }
};

LONG WINAPI UnhandledExceptionHandler(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS pointers)
{
    FooStackWalker walker;
    walker.ShowCallstack(::GetCurrentThread(), pointers->ContextRecord);
    ::TerminateProcess(::GetCurrentProcess(), 1);
}


int main()
{
    ::SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(UnhandledExceptionHandler);
}
```

I've gotten the stack trace to print just fine, but now getting `what` is difficult.

Is there some way I can decode the SEH exception as a C++ exception in order to call this member function before termination?

Comment: You'll get 3 ExceptionInformation words.  The 2nd is a pointer to the exception object.  You have no hope of interpreting it, no such thing as reflection in C++.  The exception filters emitted by the *catch* keyword are crucial.

Comment: @Hans: If one assumes that the thing thrown always derives from `std::exception` (which is true for many codebases), can't it be interpreted? Once you have a `std::exception` you can `dynamic_cast` down to specific exception types if need be...

Comment: Cast to *what* exception?  That's the key.  You might get *what*.

Comment: @Hans: It's a `void *` -- can't that just be `static_cast` to `std::exception*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the C++ machinery that already gives you the exception details?  It's not exclusive with SEH filters (although it *is* exclusive with `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`).  You just have to nest the handlers correctly:

```
int main()
{
    try {
        return cppexcept_main();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        //use e.what()
    }
}

int cppexcept_main()
{
    __try {
        return application_main();
    }
    __except(GrabStackTrace(GetExceptionInformation()), EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH) {
         /* never reached due to EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: I misunderstood your question.  I can't say for certain what the answer is for C++ exceptions, but I'm reasonably sure that the answer is "no".  I don't believe there's any way to distinguish between unhandled exceptions caused by SEH (e.g. access violations) and uncaught C++ exceptions, or any way to distinguish between different types of C++ exceptions.  The horse has already left the barn on that one.

Original answer below:

---

No, because an SEH exception doesn't have a `what`.  It's not a `std::exception`.  [This MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de5awhsw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says that when you're trying to catch an SEH exception as a C++ exception, it can only be caught with the ellipsis (`...`) `catch` handler.  You can use [`_set_se_translator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to define your own function which converts SEH exceptions into C++ exceptions, but at that point you're just generating your own `what` from the same information at a different place (and even then, I don't know if it'd be possible to get at it from the `UnhandledExceptionFilter`).

You have all of the information you need in the [`LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  If an access violation occurred, then `pointers->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode` will be `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` (0xC0000005).  If that happened, then you can examine the `NumberParameters` and `ExceptionInformation` variables to figure out if it was a read or write violation and the address that was attempted to be accessed.

Comment: No, I want to do the reverse -- turn a SEH exception into a C++ Exception. Of course, if the SEH exception is *not* in fact a C++ exception (MSVC++ appears to use exception code `0xE06D7363`), whatever conversion done free to fail or otherwise tell me to go to hell (in which case I don't want to try to print a stack trace anyway -- one shouldn't try to continue running after an access violation or whatever).

Comment: (It should be noted that I would be happy to do this kind of thing inside a plain C++ `catch`, but at that point the stack has been unwound so printing the stack of the throwing point is impossible)

Comment: Confirmed 0xE06D7363: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/07/30/10044061.aspx

Comment: That information is for debugging/diagnostic purposes. It is not something your program should take a dependency on, because it can change at any time.

Comment: @Raymond: I know that -- that's why I'm asking this question -- to find out if there's a supported way of doing it. (It's not going to change though unless I were to recompile and change CRTs anyway -- after all, all the bits that interpret the exception and such have to be embedded at a plain C++ `catch` site somehow)

Comment: The exception code number used to throw an object is compiler specific, maybe even version specific. So no, there is no **supported** way to handle this. If you know the exact compiler and version you are targetting, and you know the exact exception code number used and how that object is passed around (such as is described in that MSDN blog), then you can access the object. But writing such logic is definately not supported by any vendor's standard API, so you are on your own.  This is very low-level programming, and vendors don't want you to have to go that deep.